# Timeout while grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have a report screen where I do group by over 200 MB of data in DB and sometimes i get timeout, sometimes runs to completion.

How can i optimize it or make it faster?

Below is the code I have :

```
    public ActionResult CleanReport()
    {
        var count = _db.Surveys.AsNoTracking().Count();

        var result = _db.Surveys.AsNoTracking().GroupBy(x => x.Clean).Select(group => new { Clean = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

        var items = new List<PieChartModel>();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            if (item.Clean.HasValue == false)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var chartModel = new PieChartModel();

            if (item.Clean == Clean.IdareEder)
            {
                chartModel.color = "#F7464A";
                chartModel.highlight = "#FF5A5E";
            }

            if (item.Clean == Clean.Iyiydi)
            {
                chartModel.color = "#46BFBD";
                chartModel.highlight = "#5AD3D1";
            }

            if (item.Clean == Clean.Kötüydü)
            {
                chartModel.color = "#642EFE";
                chartModel.highlight = "#642EFE";
            }

            if (item.Clean == Clean.CevapYok)
            {
                chartModel.color = "#FFCC00";
                chartModel.highlight = "#FFCC66";
            }

            chartModel.label = item.Clean.Value.DisplayName();

            double per = (item.Count * 100.0) / count;
            chartModel.value = (int)Math.Round(per);

            items.Add(chartModel);
        }

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: As in all similar questions - what it the schema of the table, are there any indexes, how much data are you loading? If you try to load a lot of data, you *will* get a timeout. Have you tried executing the equivalent SQL directly against the database (looks like a simple grouping)? How long does it take? Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: Unless you are asking how to increment the timeout or how something "doesn't work", I guess the correct site for this question should be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of timeout are you getting? Database timeout, ASP.NET timeout?

Comment: @Jcl the question wouldn't be accepted in codereview, the code isn't exactly related to the issue. It's essentially a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see that now. My first understanding (as it's returning Json I assumed it was a web service) was that the timeout was actually on the asp.net response, not on the db query. I don't see the need to put the rest of the code otherwise, but yes, rereading it might be it.

Comment: I have a page where I invoke 10 of this kind of methods. I am not getting ASP.NET timeout but database. I know how to increase timeout for DBContext.

Comment: @DarthVader Increasing the timeout isn't the solution. 200 MB isn't a lot of data. What is important is whether you have indexes on the table. *Have* you tried to execute the same statement in SSMS? Did you check its execution plan? How many rows do you expect back?

Comment: Then the rest of the code is basically useless. You should rather just write the query and tell us more about your database: indexes, check execution plan, etc. Is it local to the application? Does it transfer those 200mb over a slow network? etc.

Comment: I just put indexes. I will check again.

Comment: Looks like you only expect at most 4 rows back, since you are treating `Clean` as an enum with 4 values. An index whose first column is `Clean` would speed up execution a lot.

Comment: Yeah I just indexed them. I will check the perf.